# min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find minimum element in matrix row, but there are two conditions:
1) it must be > 0
2) and this point must be not visited(`is_visited[k] is False`)
I'm trying to do next:

```
min(x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0  if is_visited[k] is False )
```

But there is an error: `min() arg is an empty sequence`

The full block of code:

```
for k in range(4):
        if matr_sum[i][k] == min(x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0  if is_visited[k] is False ) and i!=k:
            return k
```

How to resolve it? Or should I write my `min()` function? Because it works with one condition:

```
min(x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0)
```

But with two conditions, it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: so, min cannot find the minimal value in an empty sequence. makes sense. it is really up to you to figure out what you want to do about the empty sequence.

Comment: it works with one condition. Why it doesn't with two?

Comment: @Andrew: it doesn't work with two conditions because none of the values of `x` that you iterate over, pass both conditions. There's nothing for `min` to see, so it throws an exception.

Comment: It is Invalid Syntax

Comment: To add to the above, if you print `[x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0  if is_visited[k] is False]` before the problematic line, you will see that in the case that errors, the list is empty. `min([])` raises this exception, because its not obvious/defined what the minimum of no items should be.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72134168/how-does-one-save-a-plot-in-wandb-with-wandb-log

Answer (score 45):

If you want to avoid this *ValueError* in general, you can set a `default` argument to `min()`, that will be returned in case of an empty list. See described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min).

```
min([], default="EMPTY")
# returns EMPTY
```

Note that this only works in Python 3.4+

Answer (score 11):

There is no problem with the syntax. It's certainly unusual to have two `if` clauses, but it's allowed. Consider:

```
print(min(x for x in range(1,300) if x % 3 == 0 if x % 5 == 0))
```

Output:

```
15
```

However:

```
print(min(x for x in range(1,300) if x % 2 != 0 if x % 2 != 1))
```

Output:

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

There are no integers that are both odd and even, so there are no values for `min` to see, so it throws an exception.

I deduce that in your code, there are no values that pass both conditions. Python doesn't allow you to compute "the minimum of no values", mainly because it makes no sense.

You have to decide what you want to do in the case where there is no minimum because there are no values greater than `0`. For example, if you *don't* want to return `k` in that case then I might re-write your code something like this:

```
for k in range(4):
    if k != i and is_visited[k] is False:
        if matr_sum[i][k] > 0 and matr_sum[i][k] == min(x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0):
            return k
```

It might not be obvious why this helps, but assuming `matr_sum[i]` is a list or similar, then once we know `matr_sum[i][k] > 0` then we know the generator passed to `min` isn't empty, so we won't get an exception. Whereas if `matr_sum[i][k] <= 0`, then it certainly isn't equal to the smallest positive value, so there's no need to compute the `min` at all. Another way to write that would be:

```
if matr_sum[i][k] > 0 and not any(0 < x < matr_sum[i][k] for x in matr_sum[i])
```

Actually, I'd normally write `if not is_visited[k]`, but I leave it as `is False` since I don't know whether changing it would change the behaviour of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - it creates the list of x values `xs` and then only tries to find the min if `xs` is non-empty. You may need to add some logic to handle the case that `xs` *is* empty, depending on what your code is doing.

```
for k in range(4):
    if is_visited[k] is False and i != k:
        xs = [x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0]
        if xs and matr_sum[i][k] == min(xs):
            return k
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `and` operation for concatenate tow if statement :

```
min(x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0 and if is_visited[k] is False and i!=k)
```

Comment: if matr_sum[i][k] == min(x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0 and if is_visited[k] is False ) and i!=k:
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Andrew first i miss `i!=k`  you need to put it in min function ! as i edit the answer

Comment: No, guy. Invalid syntax

Comment: if matr_sum[i][k] == min(x for x in matr_sum[i] if x > 0 and if is_visited[k] is False) and i!=k:
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Andrew again you put `and i!=k` outside the parenthesis ????pls put it in , like my answer !